# Java static method

Tags: java, static

I am new to java and I wanted to know if is ok to return an object from a static method ?
Since static methods operate on a class ... I am a little confused here.
Also what if multiple threads are trying to call this ?

```
class Test
{
    public static test(List<String> input) {
        List<List<String>> res = new ... ;
        // some code
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the replies.

Comment: The above code will not compile because the return type is missing from the method declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem returning an object from static method.

Your sample is also fine with multiple threads. Each thread will create a different object on the heap and return a reference to it - so no problems, the object is not shared.

Static methods do NOT operate on a class. They are just bound to class instead of to member of that class. This means that they don't have access to any non static members of the class. Other than that, they are not very different than the non-static methods.

If your static method accessed (write or read) a static member, then it might possibly has problems with multiple threads, unless you use locking.

Comment: No, threads have their private stack in which object will be stored, not in heap space as it is shared by threads.

Comment: all objects are on the heap, man :) only the references are on the stack

Comment: Can refer http://stackoverflow.com/q/3318750/366964, this post has several samples illustrating that

Answer (score 2):

Static method is associated with class if you call it from different thread there won't be any problem for your demonstrated code since `res` would be thread local

Answer (score 2):

Here while declaring method you need to write return type of method.

for example :

```
 import java.util.List;

    class Test
    {
        public static List test(List<String> input) {
            List<List<String>> res = new ... ;
            // some code
            return res;
        }
    }
```

So, this method will return list and for static method you do not need to create object of that class

Answer (score 2):

I agree, the method is perfectly fine.

Just be careful though, the method may be thread safe, but the List that you pass in, is not.  If you (for example) iterate over the list, while another thread is inserting Strings, you may run into some problems. Strings, being immutable are thread-safe of course.

Answer (score 1):

This is okay, basically, as long as you are working with local variables only. Thus, your code sample, where you create a new `List` each time you invoke the method. Whether this is an elegant design or not is a different story.

If you use a state, e.g. some member fields, this is a different story. Multiple threads might invoke your method, and they work on the very same objects.

Answer (score 1):

Static method can access only static objects.

So if you will be using any object in your static method that is also going to be static so having same value for all threads.

So you can easily do this.

Answer (score 1):

To get a basic understanding of static variables/methods versus instance variable/methods, read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) or search for similar ones. Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173399/are-non-synchronised-static-methods-thread-safe-if-they-dont-modify-static-clas) and its answers should help explain when exactly methods are thread-safe (yours doesn't modify any data that could be shared between threads, so it's perfectly safe).

As for your code, your method signature should look something like this:

```
public static List<List<String>> test(List<String> input) {...}
```

since you'll be returning a list of lists of strings.