# How to moniter memory allocated by some java method at runtime

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am creating a java program in which my class suppose A has it's some predefined behavior. But user can over-ride my class to change its behavior. So my script will check if there is some subclass than I will call it's behavior but what if he has written some blocking code or memory leak in his code.

This may harm my process. Is there is any way in java to monitor memory allocated by some method.

Please suggest.

Comment: Do you want to monitor memory usage programmatically or are you looking for a tool that lets you connect to a running program and investigate how it uses memory?

Comment: No I don't want to moniter total process (like JMX) but i want to moniter particular method.

Comment: Have you hooked your app to a debugger and checked if it keeps track of object allocations? I vaguely remember doing something like that several years ago when hunting for a memory leak.

Comment: Then no, this cannot be done. The method or class that creates an object is not saved anywhere. You can only get global and thread-level statistics.

Answer (score 1):

> but what if he has written some blocking code or memory leek in his
>   code

First of all i suggest you document your class well. Describe what the user is allowed to do and what not. Give use cases what to do(if possible).

For the blocking code part, if you have some timing issues, you could wrap the execution of the method in say a `Future` and let a `ExecutorService` execute the code. That way you will be able to cancel the execution if the execution takes too much time.

For the memory leak issue, well i guess you are not talking about memory leaks but increased memory consumption caused by calling the overridden method. Memory leaks in java are rare after all.

You will not be able to detect the memory consumption of a method, that's not how java works. Memory is global. What will you do if for example an external library is loaded(JNI), or some library in the classpath is called that will use more memory now? You just can not tell.

Other then monitoring the overall memory consumption, there is no other way(someone please tell me if i am wrong).

Comment: Yes, similar as I have written, too... Therefore, I have suggested to use Heap analyzer tools.

Answer (score 0):

For external monitoring, you can use VisualVM or JConsole (part of JDK), for internal you can use the Runtime class:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long totalMem = rt.totalMemory();
    long maxMem = rt.maxMemory();
    long freeMem = rt.freeMemory();
```

Via the Thread class, you can check the status of all threads. Never used it directly, because application servers or batch processing APIs doing their job... So, I don't need to reinvent the wheel. And I suggest to use tools like VisualVM...

EDIT: Watch also this thread: [Why do threads share the heap space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318750/why-do-threads-share-the-heap-space)

You cannot analyze the heap usage of a single thread. If you have problems with the execution of foreign code, you should sepearate it as good as you can from other threads and analyze the thread or heap dumps. This could be done as mentioned with VisualVM or JConsole which was also added by Oracle (or SUN).

Comment: OP explicitly asked for a way to monitor memory allocated by a method, not for a way to monitor memory allocated by the whole JVM, which this suggestion does.

Comment: But analyzing the whole JVM can also help. Yes, maybe by using DEBUG mode, too. And a method is not consuming memory... Even a thread doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has quite a good document about solving memory leaks. It suggests that one should use NetBeans Profiler as a tool.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html

I believe you can use the same debugging API for checking against misbehaving code while it is running, but that will come with a performance penalty and is probably akin to killing a fly with a sledgehammer. I personally would not let anything like that to run in production. Instead I would rely on rigorous testing and peer review.

Comment: NetBeans profiler is also just a JVM analyzing tool, with the disadvantage that you probably have to use the NetBeans IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what sort of behavior that the subclass can do, then we might think of options. For example, if it's a database related operation, we can force them to do connection clean ups, if it's file based, we can force them to read the file through your class and check for how big the file is, if it's any http call or some other streaming functionality, we can look at enforcing constraints accordingly.

If you're just worried about the heap size utilization and memory leaks there, you might want to look at http://java.dzone.com/tips/getting-jvm-heap-size-used which explains how to get runtime memory programatically. But then you'll have to do periodic checks and you can never be sure of whether a memory usage is caused by the subclass behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [this](https://code.google.com/p/java-allocation-instrumenter/) while i was trying to build up an agent that records memory allocations:

In the post [How to track any object creation in Java since freeMemory() only reports long-lived objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810212/how-to-track-any-object-creation-in-java-since-freememory-only-reports-long-li) it is specified that there is an open source project [Java Allocation Instrumenter](https://code.google.com/p/java-allocation-instrumenter/) that you could use to register your own callback (it has examples too) and using that you are able to obtain what you need.

I started few days ago to work on a similar project and while researching i found your question and the below post.

I personally needed this kind of code in some unit tests to check if one allocates too many objects inside critical methods and found that using `Runtime` class was not appropiate because `Garbage collector` may interfere and the test recorded negative numbers for allocated memory.