# Java list expand strategy

Tags: java, arraylist

for example, in an `ArrayList`, each item is very big, and the size of the list may be large enough to exceed the size of memory. What is the strategy to expand a list in this situation?

Thanks for all the replies. I have encountered such a problem that receiving a list of object by remote calling, and each object in the list may be quite large while the size of the list may be 10000 or more. I wonder how to store this list into memory during the execution.

`List<BigItem> list = queryService.queryForList(params...);`

Comment: The fact that each item is very big doesn't have much to do with expanding the ArrayList. When the ArrayList becomes large it extends the array of *references*, so it always extends by the same amount of memory, no matter what the elements are. What takes up memory are the actual objects being added to the list, and if you create many of them, it doesn't matter whether you put them in a list or an array or any other collection. So please explain your question in more detail as it is not really clear what your problem is now.

Comment: You don't expand the list; you change your strategy to not keep everything in memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very generic, but I think it is possible to give a certain "fact based" answer nonetheless:

If your setup is as such that memory becomes a bottleneck; then your application needs to be aware about that fact. In other words: you need to implement **measurements** within your application.

You have to enable your application to make the decision if "growing" a list (and "loading" those expensive objects for example) is possible, or not.

A simple starting point is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049058/how-to-moniter-memory-allocated-by-some-java-method-at-runtime); but of course, this is really a complicated undertaking. Your code has to constantly monitor its memory usage; and take appropriate steps if you get closer to your limits.

Alternatively, you should to *profiling* to really **understand** the memory consumption "behavior" of your application. There is no point in a putting effort into "self-controlling" ... if your application happens to have various memory leaks for example. Or if your code is generating "garbage" on a rate that makes the garbage collector spin constantly.

You see, a lot of aspects come into play here. You should focus on them one by one. Start with **understanding** your application; then decide if you have to improve its "garbage collection" behavior; or if you have go down the full nine yards and make your application manage itself!